# Is there a way to copy multiple command output to clipboard?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, prompt

I have 4 commands chained together and I want to copy the output of all four of them to the clipboard at once (basically append the clipboard with the output of each). Is this possible. The command I am running is this.

```
ipconfig | findstr "IPv4" & systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS      Name" & wmic cpu get caption & wmic diskdrive get model & wmic diskdrive get size
```

Comment: `(command1 & command2 &command3 ) | clip`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Please post as answer...

Comment: I would suggest certainly for speed purposes getting rid of the systeminfo command and replacing it with `wmic os get caption`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would do it like this:

```
(command1 & command2 & command3 ) | clip
```

Comment: Confirmed this works by doing a simple test: `(echo 1 & echo 2) | clip`

Comment: Thank you very much Mark. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Jasonca1 If you put parentheses around, it hasn't to be a one liner. Multiple lines are easier to read/maintain.

Comment: Nice solution, although it's problematic with the commands of the question, since all of them produce ASCII/ANSI output, except for `wmic`, which returns Unicode text, which all becomes mixed up; see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604222/5047996) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985724)...