# How to format batch command result on text file

Tags: batch-file

I am retrieving computer information using the batch script below,

```
(
    systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name" /c:"Domain" /c:"OS Name" /c:"OS Version" /c:"System Manufacturer" /c:"System Model" /c:"System type" /c:"Total Physical Memory" /c:"Available Physical Memory" 

    wmic bios get serialnumber

) > "getPCinfo.txt"
```

then result on the text file is

```
Host Name:                 Host
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.16299 N/A Build 16299
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              Latitude 7480
BIOS Version:              Dell Inc. 1.7.3, 10/11/2017
Total Physical Memory:     8,077 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2,450 MB
Domain:                    Domain.Domain.Domain.net
S e r i a l N u m b e r     

 3 R K 5 M H 2
```

May I know how can I format the Serial Number into the same format as previous info as something like :-

```
S e r i a l N u m b e r :   3 R K 5 M H 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't like overly long lines in scripts - you loose overview too fast.
This batch uses findstr's default RegEx mode, anchors at line begin with `/B`
and substitutes the spaces in the search strings with a dot.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\22\Get-PCInfo.cmd
@Echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A IN ('
  wmic bios get serialnumber /value ^|find /I "serialnumber"
') DO For %%C in (%%B) Do Set "BIOS=%%A:              %%C"

Set "Find=Host.Name Domain OS.Name OS.Version System.Manufacturer"
Set "Find=%Find% System.Model System.type Total.Physical.Memory"
Set "Find=%Find% BIOS.Version Available.Physical.Memory"

( systeminfo | findstr /I /B "%Find%"
  Echo=%BIOS%
) >getPCinfo.txt
```

Sample output:

```
> type getPCinfo.txt
Host Name:                 HOST
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.16299 N/A Build 16299
System Manufacturer:       System manufacturer
System Model:              System Product Name
System Type:               x64-based PC
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. 1408   , 09/21/2010
Total Physical Memory:     24.566 MB
Available Physical Memory: 14.753 MB
Domain:                    Doamin
SerialNumber:              Number
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
@echo off

systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name" /c:"Domain" /c:"OS Name" /c:"OS Version" /c:"System Manufacturer" /c:"System Model" /c:"System type" /c:"Total Physical Memory" /c:"Available Physical Memory">"getPCinfo.txt"

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G IN ('wmic bios get serialnumber /value ^|find /I "serialnumber"') DO >>"getPCinfo.txt" echo %%G :   %%H
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a character encoding issue: `systeminfo` returns ASCII/ANSI text, but `wmic` returns Unicode text.

[Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694) already showed a way to convert the `wmic` output to ASCII/ANSI text in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50980003), although I would write it a bit differently in order to avoid conversion artefacts like orphaned carriage-return (CR) characters:

```cmd
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name" /c:"Domain" /c:"OS Name" /c:"OS Version" /c:"System Manufacturer" /c:"System Model" /c:"System type" /c:"Total Physical Memory" /c:"Available Physical Memory" > "getPCInfo.txt"
for /F "delims=" %%H in ('wmic BIOS get SerialNumber /VALUE') do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("%%H") do >> "getPCInfo.txt" echo %%I:              %%J
```

---

Anyway, here is another method using a temporary file:

```cmd
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name" /c:"Domain" /c:"OS Name" /c:"OS Version" /c:"System Manufacturer" /c:"System Model" /c:"System type" /c:"Total Physical Memory" /c:"Available Physical Memory" > "getPCInfo.txt"
wmic bios get serialnumber /VALUE > "getPCInfo.tmp"
type "getPCInfo.tmp" >> "getPCInfo.txt"
del "getPCInfo.tmp"
```

This works only if the hosting `cmd` instance is *not* run in Unicode mode (see its `/U` option), but the default is ASCII/ANSI (`/A`) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an untested PowerShell version, *only because of how long systeminfo takes*:

**PCInfo.ps1**

```ps1
$Properties = @{  
  Host_Name = (GWMI Win32_OperatingSystem).CSName
  OS_Name = (GWMI Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
  OS_Version = GWMI Win32_OperatingSystem | % {$_.Version+' build '+$_.BuildNumber}
  System_Manufacturer = (GWMI Win32_ComputerSystem).Manufacturer
  System_Model = (GWMI Win32_Computersystem).Model
  BIOS_Version = (GWMI Win32_BIOS).SMBIOSBIOSVersion
  Total_Physical_Memory = GWMI Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure Capacity -Sum | % {[String]$([Math]::Round(($_.Sum / 1MB),0))+' MB'}
  Available_Physical_Memory = GWMI Win32_OperatingSystem | % {[String]$([Math]::Round(($_.FreePhysicalMemory * 1KB / 1MB),0))+' MB'}
  Domain = GWMI Win32_Computersystem | % {$_.DNSHostName +'.'+$_.Domain}
  Serial_Number = (GWMI Win32_BIOS).SerialNumber}
$ColumnWidth = ($Properties.Keys | Measure -Max Length).Maximum
$Properties.GetEnumerator() | Sort Name| % {"{0,-$ColumnWidth}: {1}" -F $_.Key, $_.Value}
```

To run it, *change the paths as necessary and* enter the following at the Command Prompt:

```dos
PowerShell -NoP -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Users\YHTAN\Desktop\PCInfo.ps1">"C:\Users\YHTAN\Desktop\PCInfo.txt"
```