# Formatting results in .CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to create a basic script that runs and checks for basic system info but I want the output to be formatted so the results are on the same line and easily readable.

```
@Echo Off

systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"

wmic cpu get name, status

systeminfo | findstr /C:"Total Physical Memory"

@echo off & setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "volume=C:"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %volume%') DO (
    SET "diskfree=!disktotal!"
    SET "disktotal=!diskavail!"
    SET "diskavail=%%j"
)
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%i IN ("%disktotal% %diskavail%") DO SET "disktotal=%%i"& SET "diskavail=%%j"
ECHO(Total Space:            %disktotal:~0,-9% GB
ECHO(Available Space:        %diskavail:~0,-9% GB

systeminfo | find "System Boot Time:"

systeminfo | find "System Type:"

Echo Antivirus: & wmic /node:localhost /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct Get DisplayName | findstr /V /B /C:displayName || echo No Antivirus installed
```

[image: Current output]

The main example of this would be the wmic command placing the result on the next line rather than the same line.

Also any tips of better ways of scripting what I currently have would be appreciated.

Comment: [`wmic`](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) features a `/VALUE` you might be interested in. Anyway, why are you executing `systeminfo` dozends of times? do it once and use [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) with multiple (space-separated) search strings instead...

Comment: What do you mean by `/VALUE`? And I am  aware I could reduce using `systeminfo` as many times but I have very little understanding of  cmd and scripting at the moment, are you able  to provide an example of how I might include multiple strings using the `findstr` command?

Thanks

Comment: Check the output of `wmic CPU get Name,Status /VALUE`. And `findstr /L "abc def"` defines two literal search strings...

Comment: Like @aschipfl suggested run systeminfo only once and select the lines with findstr and a multi search like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50988168/6811411)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('systeminfo') do (
    if "%%~A" == "OS Name" (
        call :print "%%~A" %%B
    ) else if "%%~A" == "OS Version" (
        call :print "%%~A" %%B
        call :cpu
    ) else if "%%~A" == "Total Physical Memory" (
        call :print "%%~A" %%B
        call :fsutil C:
    ) else if "%%~A" == "System Boot Time" (
        call :print "%%~A" %%B
    ) else if "%%~A" == "System Type" (
        call :print "%%~A" %%B
    )
)

:next
call :antivirus

pause
exit /b

:print
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "name=%~1"
if not defined name exit /b
set "name=%~1                                "
set "full=%*"
set "full=!full:,=!"
set "data="
set "skip1="

for %%A in (!full!) do (
    if not defined skip1 (
        set "skip1=defined"
    ) else if not defined data (
        set "data=%%~A"
    ) else (
        set "data=!data! %%~A"
    )
)

echo !name:~,30!: !data!
exit /b

:antivirus
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "antivirus="

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('
 2^>nul wmic /node:localhost
 /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct
 Get DisplayName /value
 ^| findstr /i /b /c:"DisplayName" ^|^| echo No Antivirus installed
') do set "antivirus=%%~A"

if /i "!antivirus:~,12!" == "DisplayName=" set "antivirus=!antivirus:~12!"

call :print Antivirus "!antivirus!"
exit /b

:cpu
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic cpu get name^, status /value') do (
    call :print "%%~A" %%B
)
exit /b

:fsutil
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
2>nul >nul net session || exit /b

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('2^>nul fsutil volume diskfree %1') do (
    set "name=%%~A"
    set "value=%%~B"
    call :print "!name:bytes=GBs!" !value:~,-9!
)
exit /b
```

The `fsutil` command outputs alittle different.
I chose an easy option if it is OK.

Unsure of antivirus output as you need both results of
installed or not to be sure.

It only runs `systeminfo` once to save time.

Look at `set /?` for information about substitution that
is used.

The `net session` command is used to test if script is run as Admin.
If not Admin, then `fsutil` will be skipped as it requires Admin.

Look at `for /?` for usage of the command that is used in the script.

Use of `enabledelayedexpansion` is used to prevent special
characters being exposed which may cause error otherwise.
And used in code blocks to delay expansion as needed.

Remove comma from value strings which get replaced with a space.
A comma is often used as thousands separator and numbers look odd
with a space instead. This occurs because of usage of a simple
`for` loop interpreting comma as a argument separator. Some other
chararters may also do this though perhaps a space maybe better
than none in their case.

Comment: There'll be no antivirus output because `findstr /B /C:displayName` should be `FindStr /B /C:"DisplayName"`, _or you should include the **`/I`** option because the output should always carry a capitalised `D`_!

Comment: @Compo, thankyou. I updated the answer with both suggestions.

Comment: Thank you Michael, this is exactly what I was looking for except for the Total & available space on the c drive although I have found a way to include this.

Answer (score 0):

The output of WMIC is unicode !

The trailing `<CR>` can be removed by passing the value through another FOR /F loop. This also removes the phantom "blank" line (actually a `<CR>`)

```bat
@Echo Off
Call :GET_CPU name CPU_Name

Set "WMIC_Antivirus=wmic /node:localhost /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct Get DisplayName ^| findstr /V /B /C:displayName"
@For /F "delims=" %%I in ('%WMIC_Antivirus%') do ( 
    for /f "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "Antivirus=%%A"
)

echo CPU       :   %CPU_Name%
echo Antivirus :   %Antivirus%
pause & exit
::----------------------------------------------------
:GET_CPU 
Set "WMIC_CPU=wmic cpu get name /Value"
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  '%WMIC_CPU% ^| find /I "%~1" 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::----------------------------------------------------
```

You can try to save the output into a text file :

```bat
@Echo Off
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment" >nul 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                      **************************************
ECHO                       Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                      **************************************

    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Log=%~dp0Log.txt"
If exist "%Log%"  Del "%Log%" 
Call :GET_CPU name CPU_Name
Set "WMIC_Antivirus=wmic /node:localhost /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct Get DisplayName ^| findstr /V /B /C:displayName"
@For /F "delims=" %%I in ('%WMIC_Antivirus%') do ( 
    for /f "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "Antivirus=%%A"
)

(
    Echo.
    Echo ***************************** General infos ***********************************
    Echo.
    Echo Running under: %username% on profile: %userprofile%
    Echo Computer name: %computername%
    Echo.
    systeminfo
    Echo Operating System:
    Echo PROCESSOR ARCHITECTURE : %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
    echo NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS : %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%
    echo PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER : %PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER%
    echo PROCESSOR_LEVEL : %PROCESSOR_LEVEL%
    echo PROCESSOR_REVISION : %PROCESSOR_REVISION%
    echo OS TYPE : %OS%
    echo(
    echo Program files path : %Programfiles%
    echo Program files(86^) path  : %Programfiles(86^)%
    echo ProgramW6432 path : %ProgramW6432%
    echo PSModulePath : %PSModulePath%
    echo SystemRoot : %SystemRoot%
    echo Temp Folder : %Temp%
    echo CPU       :   !CPU_Name!
    echo Antivirus :   !Antivirus!
    Echo.
    Echo **************************** Drives infos *************************************
    Echo.
    Echo Listing currently attached drives:
    wmic logicaldisk get caption,description,volumename | find /v ""
    Echo.
    Echo Physical drives information:
    for /F "tokens=1-3" %%A in ('fltmc volumes^|find ":"') do echo %%A %%B %%C
)>>"%Log%"
Start "" "%Log%" & exit
::----------------------------------------------------
:GET_CPU 
Set "WMIC_CPU=wmic cpu get name /Value"
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  '%WMIC_CPU% ^| find /I "%~1" 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What would I need to change to make this work with other WMIC commands like  "wmic cpu get name, status" or "WMIC Product Where "Name='Name here'" get name, version"

Comment: Okay so I have found the answer 

Set WMIC_CMD=wmic cpu get name
@For /F "delims=" %%C in ('%WMIC_CMD%') do ( 
    for /f "delims=" %%N IN ("%%C") DO SET "CPU=%%N"
)
echo CPU Type :     %CPU%

But I still am trying to format the spacing so they roughly align, is there a simple way of doing such a thing?

Comment: This doesn't align the system info commands with the wmic commands though, getting the wmic on one line was part of the issue but I need all the results aligned.

Thank you for your help Hackoo

Comment: @user10073459 I added another code to save results output into a text file ! Please check the new code !