# Converting CMD output into CSV file

Tags: windows, cmd

I am currently using this quick batch file to get info that I need from a variety of computers. My problem is that it creates the CSV file, but it is all one column. I am planning to use python to manipulate the data, but it is difficult to do so if it is all one column.

```
@echo off

(systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Name"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Model"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System type"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Total Physical Memory"
ipconfig | findstr IPv4
wmic diskdrive get size
wmic bios get serialnumber
wmic cpu get name)>>in.csv
```

Comment: 1. The output is not really a CSV file. 2. `systeminfo` needs quite some time, so calling it multiple times could be avoided by writing its output to a temporary file once and then let `findstr` gather the required information from there. 3. `systeminfo` returns ASCII/ANSI text, while `wmic` returns Unicode text; mixing them is a quite bad idea. 4. You did not specify the desired output format, neither did you provide a [mcve] of your own attempt to implement it; please take the [tour] and learn to [ask] here on this site!

Comment: ad 2. As an alternative to a temporary file, simply use multiple search strings, like `systeminfo | findstr /C:"Host Name" /C:"OS Name" ...`, etc. ad 3. take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604222/5047996) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985724)...

Comment: `Wmic /format /?` `wmic /append /?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All output, single line, comma delimited, and sub-delimits on both IP address and disk drive, since there are multiple of those.  Sub-delimit is a semi-colon.

## Output:

```
MyBox,36527083,Packard Bell,3-2,Microsoft Windows 10,x64-based PC,17087881216,192.168.121.1;192.168.3.1;10.11.18.112,Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz,2000396321280;63992678400;4000784417280;512105932800;1500299297280
```

## Cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "zManufacturer="
set "zHostName="
set "zOsName="
set "zSystemModel="
set "zSystemType="
set "zTotalPhysicalMemory="
set "zIpAddresses="
set "zHddSizes="
set "zCpuName="
set "zBiosSerial="

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims=," %%A in ('wmic computersystem get Manufacturer^,Model^,TotalPhysicalMemory^,SystemType^,Workgroup /format:csv ^| findstr ","') do (
    set "zHostName=%%A"
    set "zManufacturer=%%B"
    set "zSystemModel=%%C"
    set "zSystemType=%%D"
    set "zTotalPhysicalMemory=%%E"
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /i ipv4') do set "zIpAddresses=!zIpAddresses!%%A"
set "zIpAddresses=!zIpAddresses:~1!"
set "zIpAddresses=!zIpAddresses: =;!"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=|" %%A in ('wmic os get name ^|findstr "|"') do set "zOsName=%%A"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('wmic bios get serialnumber^,version /format:csv') do set "zBiosSerial=%%A"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('wmic cpu get name^,version /format:csv') do set "zCpuName=%%A"

for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('wmic diskdrive get size^,TracksPerCylinder /format:csv ^|findstr /v /r "^$"') do set "zHddSizes=!zHddSizes!;%%A"
set "zHddSizes=!zHddSizes:~1!"

echo !zHostName!,!zBiosSerial!,!zManufacturer!,!zSystemModel!,!zOsName!,!zSystemType!,!zTotalPhysicalMemory!,!zIpAddresses!,!zCpuName!,!zHddSizes!
```