# How can I log all of the data displayed to a text file using batch scripting?

Tags: batch-file, logging

```
@echo off 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Domain"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Name" 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Manufacturer"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Model"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System type"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Total Physical Memory" 
ipconfig | findstr IPv4
echo Hard Drive Space:
wmic diskdrive get size > C:\Scripts\Testtt.txt
```

Currently the only thing getting saved to the testtt.txt file is the diskspace.

Answer (score 0):

```
(systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Domain"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Name" 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Manufacturer"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Model"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System type"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Total Physical Memory" 
ipconfig | findstr IPv4
echo Hard Drive Space:
wmic diskdrive get size ) >C:\Scripts\Testtt.txt
```

?

Comment: Nice, but there is one problem: all of the commands produce ASCII/ANSI output, except for `wmic`, which returns Unicode text, all of which becomes mixed up; see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604222/5047996) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985724)...