# ") was unexpected at this time"-- batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have this code `snippet` from a `batch` script. The script fails with:

> " ) was unexpected at this time "

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set var="value "
    echo !var!
    IF "!var!"=="value " (
        echo Perfect )
```

P.S. I need the `Delayed Expansion` in my script.

Comment: Be careful on assigning output of `wmic` to an environment variable as wmic output is in Unicode (UTF-16 Little Endian). See the answers on [How to correct variable overwriting misbehavior when parsing output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961755/) for details on how to get output of `wmic` as ANSI string.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)
Yes i am being careful on that part. Since you came up with this-- is there any way to redirect the undesired output of wmic command to NUL, that is i do not want the same to be shown in the console. Something like this:
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=7" %%f in ('wmic process where "name='java.exe'" get commandline') do ( set v=%%f )

In this very case if there are no spawning instances of 'java.exe' i see an output in the console- No Instance(s) Available
That is correct, but i dont want the same to be displayed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The excerpt you've posted works without error messages.Though if you want to include the space at the end in the variable name you can use the quotes like this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var=value "
    echo !var!
    IF "!var!" == "value " (
        echo Perfect )
```

edit based on the commends:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`"wmic process where name='java.exe' get commandline /format:value"`) do (
    call ::run  "%%~f"
)

:run
for /f "tokens=7" %%# in ("%%~1") do set "var=%%#"  
echo "!var!" 
IF "!var!"=="someValue " ( 
    echo Already running 
) Else (
 echo S
```

topped 
)

Comment: The space is mandatory. I am not able to paste the whole script here but the variable var is basically assigned with the output of a "wmic" command which includes the space.
And as the IF loop is encountered i get the above error as mentioned.

Comment: @SupratimDas  - so you'll need to paste a bigger part of your code.May be your problems are caused by [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266)

Comment: here it goes as below:
for /f "skip=1 tokens=7" %%f in ('wmic process where "name='java.exe'" get commandline') do (
  set v=%%f
  goto run
  )

:run 
 set var=!v!
 echo "!var!"
 IF "!var!"=="someValue " (
  
  echo Already running ) Else (
   echo Stopped )
Here the output from the FOR loop is set to variable v which is basically the 7th token of the first line. That variable is stored in 'var' and used in an IF check. even if the IF check is true it does not execute the commands inside the IF loop.

There are a whole lot of commands inside the IF loop, not a single statement.

Comment: sorry i am new here. I was not able to put the code as it should look like. Its a bit clumsy

Comment: I got this now..I separated parts of the code into different files and started appending the parts of the as and when it was working. Astonishingly i dont get the error now. :)