# how to get rid off the NUL's in the text file with the help of .bat script

Tags: batch-file

NUL characters in the text file, If I copy these characters to notepad they show just spaces, but my validate bat script which reads this and does some validation is halting at these NUL characters

its a feed file containing some junk characters, how to removed them with teh bat script.

I have tried with the below, its not happening

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion > "%OutputFile%"
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=|" %%a in ("%InputFile%") do (
set s=%%a
>> "%OutputFile%" echo.!s:~24!
)
```

I am not having good knowledge on writing bat scripts, but need to fix this.
appreciate your help.

Comment: `find /V "" < "%InputFile%" > "%OutputFile%"` replaces NUL characters by spaces...

Comment: Are you sure that the text file you want to process from command line is not UTF-16 Little Endian encoded? See for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43052862/3074564) in case of not knowing anything about text encoding.