# a filename with spanish accent é does not display correctly in batch file

Tags: batch-file, escaping

When running a batch file with a file name containing spanish accent é, I am noticing it does not decode properly and hence the batch does not run. I tried saving the batch file as UTF-8, ASCII or UTF-16LE, but to no avail. Anyways to escape the character in the batch file. hypothetical example is.

inside the batch file:

rename XXXéxxx.pdf AAAéAAA.pdf

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Using another language (code page) in a batch file made for others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981387/) and [CMD Can't read Danish characters when I execute .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046559/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using another language (code page) in a batch file made for others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981387/using-another-language-code-page-in-a-batch-file-made-for-others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use **CHCP**

try to ad one of these into your batch:

```
CHCP 852   > NUL
CHCP 1250  > NUL
CHCP 1252  > NUL
CHCP 1145  > NUL    
CHCP 20284 > NUL
```

last two are particulary spain based ([here is the full list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx))

CHCP stands for "CODE PAGE" and you just need to place it at the begining of your batch

also note that batch always needs to be ASCII

Comment: `CHCP` is the abbreviation of CHange Code Page. Running `chcp` without any parameter displays active code page. Wikipedia article about [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) explains that a character is for a computer a series of bits with the values 0 or 1 whereby 8 bits form a byte and it depends on rules how a byte value should be interpreted by a program. Wikipedia article about [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) lists all code pages with links to pages listing the characters of documented code pages.

Comment: by they way, if i manually copy the string into cmd window and execute it, it works fine.

Comment: This actually did work!!! Thank you ver much! Here is what I did to fix it.  My text file was output from SAS. After finagling with variety of encoding, I managed to get the one that works best. encoding=ANYANSI. After this, I had to play with variety of code pages you listed above. The best one is 1252  for the reason, it accommodates not only a single `, but also ~ above letters that make up spanish accents. I did this in the batch file:   CHCP 1252 > NULL  (then on the next row was my code that invokes pdf tools, etc.). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: "batch always needs to be ASCII": `echo ¡No, it doesn't!` ASCII wasn't even a separate codepage until very late.