# Special characters when using Windows batch files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, special-characters, handbrake

I'm having trouble running Windows batch files using Handbrake, whereby if a source file contains special characters then I get an error saying it can't find the source file because for some reason Windows converts special characters into unreadable text when running the batch file. For example:

```
HandbrakeCLI.exe -i % äöü日本語のキーボード é.avi -o % äöü日本語のキーボード é.mp4 --scan
```

If I copy the above and put it directly into CMD then it works. However, if I put it in a batch file then it fails. Any idea on how to make the batch files open successfully?

Comment: quick and dirty: Close your editor, from command line, `>>file.bat echo HandbrakeCLI.exe -i % äöü日本語のキーボード é.avi -o % äöü日本語のキーボード é.mp4 --scan`, open it again in your editor and copy/paste that line to where you need it (ignore strange or seemingly missing characters)

Comment: @Stephan thanks for this. The only issue is I'm using this in a much larger automation program so I wouldn't be able to manually do this every time.

Comment: Then maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046559/cmd-cant-read-danish-characters-when-i-execute-bat-file) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try doubling the % signs, as you'll need to escape them in a saved file. See more escape characters at https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php