# Read text file content using batch file command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have text file having content like

> 8.4.0.154
>
> newline

I have written below command in a batch file to read the first line means 8.4.0.154

```
set /p ClientSideUnitTestDestinationLocation=<%scriptLocation%\assemblyVersion.txt
Echo %ClientSideUnitTestDestinationLocation%
```

here it is just printing 8 prefixes with some special symbol as shown in below image

[image: printing only 8 prefixes with some special symbol]

could anyone help me out here to figure it out that why am not able to read complete number in batch file and print it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You usually see something like this when the file you're reading isn't saved with ANSI encoding.

Comment: Probably your file has a leading BOM

Comment: @GerhardBarnard -  Nothing is getting printed.

Comment: @picnic4u yeah, ignore that comment, I did not format correctly. Do you have notepad++? Did you perhaps test other encoding yet? the line before your `set` do `chcp 65001`

Comment: Please read Wikipedia article about [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), first two chapters of UltraEdit power tip [Working with Unicode in UltraEdit/UEStudio](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/unicode.html) and the two referenced articles, the Wikipedia pages about [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) and [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Windows command processor interprets by default any text file as being encoded with one byte per character using code page as displayed on running `chcp` in cmd window.

Comment: The OEM code page used by Windows command processor `cmd.exe` depends on country configured for the user account used on running the batch file. The code page can be modified within a batch file using command `chcp` (change code page). For even more details see on Stack Overflow [CMD can't read Danish characters when I execute .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052862/3074564) and [Using another language (code page) in a batch file made for others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48982681/3074564).

Comment: You could try the following to read and convert your Unicode file properly: `for /F %I in ('type "%scriptLocation%\assemblyVersion.txt"') do @echo %I`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was creating this text file using PowerShell script using below command:

```
param ([string] $dllPath = $null,[string] $textFile = $null)
$version = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllPath).GetName().Version.ToString()
$version > $textFile
```

The text file was not getting created with ANSI encoding hence, unable to read using a batch file.

Now, I changed the above code as below and it is working.

```
param ([string] $dllPath = $null,[string] $textFile = $null)
$version = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllPath).GetName().Version.ToString()
$version | Out-File $textFile -Encoding Ascii
```

I am able to read the text file content using below command

```
set /p ClientSideUnitTestDestinationLocation=<%scriptLocation%\assemblyVersion.txt
Echo %ClientSideUnitTestDestinationLocation%
```