# Accented letters are not recognized by CMD

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to remove local group to prevent access to the machine:

```
net localgroup "Utilisateurs" /Delete "Utilisateur authentifiés (S-1-5-11)"
```

The command above is not working because of accented letter "é".

Comment: Perhaps `chcp` will help! Open a Command Prompt window and enter `chcp /?` at the prompt to read the usage information. BTW, you're most likely looking for a code page of `65001`.

Comment: I want to replace "é" by code ascii code or something recongnised by cmd

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for neither group deletion nor membership removal - `/delete` _always_ goes last

Comment: See [Why are Danish characters not displayed as in text editor on executing batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046559/) It is exactly about same issue: missing knowledge about [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Windows command processor expects the batch file encoded with [OEM 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) (most likely, depends on country, run `chcp` in cmd window to see used code page), but batch file is written using [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252) (most likely, depends also on country).

Comment: Windows-1252 encodes character `é` with one byte with hexadecimal value `E9`. But byte `E9` is interpreted with OEM 850 as character `Ú`. So either use `chcp 1252` in your batch file before using this command line or write in batch file in GUI text editor an OEM 850 encoded `é` with hexadecimal byte value `82` being displayed Windows-1252 interpreted as `‚` in GUI text editor using Windows-1252. Note: Character `‚` (single low-9 quotation mark) is not ASCII character `,` (comma) even if the used font displays these two different characters identical.