# Trim string content and rename file

Tags: batch-file, text-files

In a text file I have 1000 of rows, each row has below data:

```
ABCDqwqqwq321890821dsapodsaidadopd-9sa-9asd-9sa00sahjkhjsakdhdsddsad                           JhKyy120320171212
```

I need to delete the characters (90 characters onwards) from each line
and save file as `Test_DDMMYYYY.txt`.

Below is my code, I'm not able to get the output.

Any suggestions please?

```
@echo off &setlocal
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (*.*txt) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:~,90!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>Test_DDMMYYYY.txt
```

Also using this code for renaming the txt file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

set datestamp=%DD%%MM%%YYYY%
set fullstamp=%DD%%MM%%YYYY%

ren "C:\test\Test_.txt" "Test_%fullstamp%.txt"
```

Comment: Please provide a **specific question title**! The one you stated is completely useless! Consult this: [ask]

Comment: without trying, three lines catched my attention: `set "line=!line:~,90!"`, `))>Test_DDMMYYYY.txt` and `ren "C:\test\Test_.txt" "Test_%fullstamp%.txt"`

Comment: if I specifically mention any file name here (*.* txt) do ( I get the output file with all the required data, for e.g. @echo off &setlocal
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (

Comment: @ Mofi, below code worked perfectly fine, thank you very much. One more small help i need is that I want to use the same file name as the original fine name e.g. Test_05_14_2017_01 (Test_MM_DD_YYYY_Version ID "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch code for copying each line not being empty and not starting with a semicolon to a new file with with local date in format `DDMMYYYY` in file name with truncating each line after the first 90 characters could be for example:

```
@echo off
if not exist "Test.txt" goto :EOF

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDate=%%I"
set "FileDate=%LocalDate:~6,2%%LocalDate:~4,2%%LocalDate:~0,4%

del "Test_%FileDate%.txt" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("Test.txt") do set "Line=%%I" & echo !Line:~0,90!>>"Test_%FileDate%.txt"
endlocal
```

The command

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE
```

outputs UTF-16 Little Endian encoded for example:

> LocalDateTime=20170513195342.921000+120

So the first line is an empty line and the second line contains the local date in format `YYYYMMDD` after the equal sign independent on region and languages settings defined for the current user account. And there are output 2 more empty lines.

Command **FOR** has some problems on parsing UTF-16 LE encoded output which results in interpreting last empty line not as empty line, but as a line containing just a carriage return. Details about this issue can be found for example in answer on [Batch: How to correct variable overwriting misbehavior when parsing output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965431/3074564).

The command **FOR** as used here splits each line up into two substrings (tokens) using the equal sign as delimiter because of `delims==` and assigns just the second string to loop variable `I` because of `tokens=2`. This means that `20170513195342.921000+120` is assigned to environment variable `LocalDate`.

The issue with last empty line being interpreted as line with a carriage return is worked around because of `tokens=2` because the line with just carriage return can't be split up into two tokens and for that reason the misinterpreted last empty line of output of **WMIC** is also ignored here by **FOR**.

The local date/time string is reformatted to just `DDMMYYYY` as requested by using command **SET** with 3 string substitutions.

**Hint:** File names using `YYYYMMDD` or better readable `YYYY-MM-DD` are automatically sorted by date when being displayed sorted by file name. Therefore `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DD` would be better than `DDMMYYYY` as date format in file name.

Then the output file is deleted if existing already with redirecting the error message on output file not existing to device `NUL` to suppress it.

The second **FOR** parses the lines of file `Test.txt` even with enclosing the file name in double quotes because of option `usebackq`. Empty lines are skipped as also lines starting with a semicolon. But all other lines are processed without splitting the lines because of option `delims=` which turns off default splitting on spaces and horizontal tabs and processing further only the first substring. So each non empty line not starting with a semicolon is assigned to loop variable `I` before processing the command line.

The line is next assigned to environment variable `Line`.

**Note 1:** Because of enabled delayed expansion as needed next with this solution a line containing 1 or more exclamation marks would not be processed correct because of interpreting each exclamation mark as begin or end of a reference to an environment variable with delayed expansion. So a different batch code would be necessary if the file could contain also exclamation marks in first 90 characters of each line.

**Note 2:** The posted line in question from input file has only 68 characters and there was not posted what should be written for this line into output file. I hope that I understood the task correct.

With operator `&` two commands are specified on one command line to execute after the command `set "Line=%%I"` one more command to output just the first 90 characters from input file with redirecting this output from handle **STDOUT** to file with local date in file name with appending this line to existing output file contents.

The truncation of the line to first 90 characters within **FOR** loop requires delayed expansion or a different code like using a subroutine.

Once the input file `Test.txt` is completely processed line by line, the previous command process environment is restored and batch file execution terminates.

Here is an alternate solution which avoids the usage of delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
if not exist "Test.txt" goto :EOF

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDate=%%I"
set "FileDate=%LocalDate:~6,2%%LocalDate:~4,2%%LocalDate:~0,4%

del "Test_%FileDate%.txt" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("Test.txt") do set "Line=%%I" & call :OutputLine
endlocal
goto :EOF

:OutputLine
>>"Test_%FileDate%.txt" echo %Line:~0,90%
goto :EOF
```

A subroutine is used here to output just the first 90 characters of each line to the output file.

The redirection operator `>>` and the output file name are specified first on command line because of

```
echo %Line:~0,90%>>"Test_%FileDate%.txt"
```

could result with immediate environment variable expansion and a line ending with a space and a number in range `1` to `9` in wrong file output.

This solution also does not work when a line to output contains characters with special meaning for Windows command interpreter like `&`, `|`, `<`, `>`, ... Windows command interpreter is not really designed for text editing. Text editors are designed for text editing.

The first solution rewritten to process each *.txt file in current directory except the output file also written into current directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDate=%%I"
set "FileDate=%LocalDate:~6,2%%LocalDate:~4,2%%LocalDate:~0,4%

del "Test_%FileDate%.txt" 2>nul
for /F "delims=" %%T in ('dir *.txt /A-D /B 2^>nul') do for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%%T") do set "Line=%%I" & echo !Line:~0,90!>>"Test_%FileDate%.txt"
endlocal
```

The file contents processing **FOR** loop is nested within one more **FOR** loop which runs command **DIR** listing all *.txt files (and not directories) because of `/A-D` in bare format (file name and file extension only without path) because of `/B`.

This list of file names of command **DIR** is processed line by line by outer **FOR** without splitting up the file names and running the inner **FOR** loop which processes the lines of the text file.

`2^>nul` redirects the error message output by **DIR** if no *.txt file found in current directory to device **NUL** to suppress it. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with `^` to be interpreted by Windows command interpreter as literal character on parsing **FOR** command line, but as redirection operator on executing **DIR** command line in one more command process started by **FOR** to execute the command.

`2>nul` in the command (line) to execute by **FOR** would result in an exit of batch execution because of a syntax error because a redirection for **FOR** can't be specified at this position in the command line.

Another variant which processes also each *.txt file in current directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%T in ('dir *.txt /A-D /B 2^>nul') do (
    del "%%~nT.tmp" 2>nul
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%%T") do set "Line=%%I" & echo !Line:~0,90!>>"%%~nT.tmp"
    if exist "%%~nT.tmp" (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\fc.exe "%%~nT.tmp" "%%T" /A >nul
        if errorlevel 1 ( move /Y "%%~nT.tmp" "%%T" ) else ( del "%%~nT.tmp" )
    )
)
endlocal
```

The truncated lines of each *.txt file are written into a *.tmp file with same name as the current *.txt file instead of writing all truncated lines into same output file.

After processing a *.txt file, the *.tmp file replaces the *.txt file if its content is different to content of the *.txt file. Otherwise the temporary file is deleted on *.tmp file being equal the *.txt file and the text file is kept unmodified.

So finally all *.txt files in current directory have no line longer 90 characters.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `fc /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`

Read also [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) and the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).