# Why is "ECHO is off" displayed after output of data of interest on running WMIC in a FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, wmic

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* skip=1 delims=\" %%b in ('wmic /node:%CompName% COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME') do echo %%b
```

Output:

```
domain\username
ECHO is off.
```

Expected result:

```
username
```

Notes: The variable `CompName` will be set prior. This can be ignored.
This code is a part of a larger code I am writing for this batch file where I'll just need to pull the `username` to have it set as a variable.

Pseudo code:

```
set TargetUsername = (results from above)
future code (possibly used for other parts of the code)
```

Comment: `tokens=*` prevents `for /F` from splitting a string into tokens; try with `tokens=1` instead; read the help of `for /?`! To prevent `echo` from returning the message `ECHO is off.` when it receives an empty string, write `echo(%%b`...

Comment: Setting it to token=2 fixed this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues causing `ECHO is off.` output on running the batch code.

The first one is using `tokens=*` which results in getting assigned to loop variable `b` always the entire line independent on `delims=\` option.

The second issue is caused by the fact that **wmic** always outputs the data Unicode encoded using UTF-16 Little Endian format with byte order mark (BOM) with always a blank line at end of output. The command **for** fails to interpret the Unicode output correct as it interprets the last blank line as line having just a carriage return which is assigned to loop variable `b` too. This bug of **for** results in execution of `echo` with a carriage return which means echo without any parameter and the result is getting output the echo status. For details about **wmic** output and the wrong interpretation of last blank line by **for** see answers on [How to correct variable overwriting misbehavior when parsing output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961755/)

The solution here is:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=\" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe /node:"%COMPUTERNAME%" COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME') do set "ComputerUserName=%%I"
echo Computer user name: %ComputerUserName%
echo Current user name:  %USERNAME%
```

The environment variable `COMPUTERNAME` is a predefined [Windows environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

The computer name can contain a space character and therefore it is recommended to enclose it in double quotes.

This batch code works because there is no second token when **for** interprets wrong the blank line at end of **wmic** Unicode output and therefore the command **set** is executed only once on processing all 3 lines of **wmic** output.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys: I just set tokens=2:

Output:

```
username
```

Comment: The next thing is to set this information to a variable, I'll let anyone know if I run into any problems