# batch file: Setting a variable to the return value from a function call

Tags: batch-file, cmd

What I am doing wrong here please? I want to make a windows `batch file` that will call an `exe`, passing in some arguments and assign the return value to a variable. I have tried lots of different variations of the following but I cant make it work.

```
SET EXE="path\to\exe"
SET TARGET_FILE="path\to\file\to\be\read\by\exe"

for /f %%i in (%EXE% -arg1 %TARGET_FILE%) do set VAR=%%i

ECHO %VAR%
PAUSE
```

What am I missing?
In case it matters, the two paths above will probably contain spaces, line `C:\Program Files\etc`.

Comment: What do you mean by the "return value" of the `exe`? Are you taking about the exit status or the standard output of the `exe`?

Comment: not the exit status. For example the `exe` can be small application that reads a photo and returns its width (or height)

Comment: Would it be too difficult to post the actual content you're assigning to `%EXE%` and `%TARGET%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following batch file should work. I have not tested, let me know if it does not.

```
SET EXE="path\to\exe"
SET TARGET_FILE="path\to\file\to\be\read\by\exe"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('"%EXE% -arg1 %TARGET_FILE%"') do (
echo %%i
)
```

Comment: The title requests to set a variable. For a single command a (code block) isn't necessary. If echo is replaced with `set var=%%i` only the last line of a multi line output will persist.

Comment: @Robert: It is not working for some reason. I had similar messages when I was trying my own script. With you script, when the path has spaces I get `C:\Programs is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`. When I move everything in a location with no spaces in the path names i get `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`. In any case, thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to add double quotes around `%EXE%`. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Robert: Ah yes! I think i got it. Inside the parentheses you need to have: `'"%EXE% -arg1 %IMG%"'`. ie single quote followed by a double quote after the opening parenthesis, matched by a double quote and a single quote just before closing parenthesis. That works on both my code and yours. Could you please edit you answer, so i can accept it. Many thanks for looking in to that.

Comment: I had missed the fact that `TARGET_FILE` could contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

First, please read my answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It makes a big difference if first double quote is left to variable name or right to equal sign on definition of an environment variable. See also [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564)

Let us look on this code:

```
@echo off
set "Executable=path\to\exe"
set "TargetFile=path\to\file\to\be\read\by\exe"

for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('"%Executable%" -arg1 "%TargetFile%" 2^>^&1') do set "Data=%%I" & goto HaveData

echo No data captured!
pause
goto :EOF

:HaveData
echo Data: %Data%
pause
```

**FOR** with option `/F` with string in round brackets enclosed in straight single quotes results in starting in background `cmd.exe /c` with using `%ComSpec% /c` with the string in round brackets as additional arguments. So one more command process is started by **FOR** in background to execute the specified command line between `'`...`'` inside the parentheses.

The full qualified file name was first assigned to an environment variable without the double quotes needed on this string containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. So the reference of the environment variable `Executable` must be now enclosed in double quotes. The same needs to be done for `TargetFile`.

**FOR** captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of the started command process for being finally processed line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself. The output to handle **STDERR** is also captured by **FOR**, but is just redirected to **STDERR** of the command process executing the batch file and therefore would be just displayed in console window.

But the executable perhaps outputs the information of interest to handle **STDERR** instead of **STDOUT**. For that reason `2>&1` is used as documented by Microsoft in article about [using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) to get output of executable written to **STDERR** redirected to **STDOUT** of background command process.

The redirection operators `>` and `&` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** processes the captured output line by line with skipping all empty lines after started executable finished and so started `cmd.exe` finished, too.

By default lines starting with `;` are also ignored by **FOR** as the semicolon is the default end of line character. `eol=` is specified to define no end of line character to avoid ignoring any non-empty line.

**FOR** splits up by default a line into substrings (tokens) using normal space and horizontal tab character as string delimiters. This string splitting behavior is most likely not wanted here. For that reason `delims=` is specified for an empty list of delimiters to disable line splitting behavior and get assigned to specified loop variable `I` the entire non-empty line currently processed by **FOR**.

The options list after `for /F` is usually specified with using `"`one or mor options`"`. This is not possible here to define an empty list of delimiters **and** no end of line character. So the options are specified not enclosed in a double quoted string. But in this case `=` and space must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal characters and not as argument separators by `cmd.exe` parsing this **FOR** command line to pass `delims= eol=` as one argument string to command **FOR**.

So if the executable defined with environment variable `Executable` outputs just one non-empty line in ANSI, this line is assigned to environment variable `Data`.

But perhaps the executable outputs the information of interest not in ASCII/ANSI, but in Unicode with UTF-16 Little Endian encoding and additionally outputs two or more empty lines as for example `wmic.exe` does. In this case a bug of **FOR** on interpreting the Unicode encoded output must be taken into account which results in deletion of environment variable `Data` after being defined with the data of interest on **FOR** processing wrong the UTF-16 LE encoded empty lines at end of captured Unicode output. For details about this bug of **FOR** see [How to correct variable overwriting misbehavior when parsing output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961755/) The solution used here is to leave the loop after first non-empty line is assigned to environment variable `Data` by a jump to code below the label `HaveData`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`