# How can I make a script to check for license in the computer?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a script for checking license in my computer. I want to get the output like this:

```
Name: Windows(R), Professional edition
 > PartialProductKey: 3V66T
 > LicenseStatus: 1
Name: Office 16, Office16ProPlusVL_KMS_Client edition
 > PartialProductKey: WFG99
 > LicenseStatus: 1
```

Here is the code to check for ***Name***:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('"wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey is not null) get Name /value"') do (echo Name: %%b)
```

For ***PartialProductKey:***

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('"wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey is not null) get PartialProductKey /value"') do (echo PartialProductKey: %%b)
```

and for ***LicenseStatus***:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('"wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey is not null) get LicenseStatus /value"') do (echo LicenseStatus: %%b)
```

But how can I show the ***PartialProductKey***, ***LicenseStatus*** below each ***Name***? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of using PowerShell instead of a CMD batch file?

Comment: No, I haven't :((

Comment: so you want something like `wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey is not null) get Name,PartialProductKey,LicenseStatus`, except ***PartialProductKey, LicenseStatus*** is below each ***Name***?

Comment: Yes, it's okay. But is there anyway to convert LicenseStatus, like 1 to Licensed, 2 to OOBGrace,...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the standard built-in VBScripts to get the information you require:

```bat
@%__AppDir__%cscript.exe /NoLogo %__AppDir__%slmgr.vbs -DLi
@For %%G In (14 15 16) Do @If Exist "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office%%G\ospp.vbs" %__AppDir__%cscript.exe /NoLogo "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office%%G\ospp.vbs" /DStatus | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /I "^License\>"
@Pause
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I prefer to use the WMIC command over slmgr.vbs or ospp.vbs to avoid the case when those files are deleted by the user, etc.

Comment: And my problem is solved. Thank you for your attention :D

Comment: @dphuc23, if you have users with sufficient privileges to remove files from the protected locations, _(`System32` and `Program Files`)_, you really should remove their privileges, or better still, the users!

Answer (score 1):

wmic does strange things with its output (it's actually the ***interaction*** between [`WMIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wmic) and [`FOR /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), adding an additional `\r` before `\r\n`. The behavior is discussed widespread across SO, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965431/12861751)). That's why `findstr /V /R "^$"` is needed:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in (
'"wmic path SoftwareLicensingProduct where (PartialProductKey is not null) get Name,PartialProductKey,LicenseStatus /format:list|findstr /V /R "^^$""'
) do (
    set "%%L"
    echo Name: !name!
    echo  ^> PartialProductKey: !PartialProductKey!
    echo  ^> LicenseStatus: !LicenseStatus!
)
```

Comment: In my computer return like this: https://i.imgur.com/uUDSrZP.png

Comment: @dphuc23 wait, will fix that