# BATCH: Variable set by for loop ends up being blank

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, variables, cmd

I am trying to run the following script

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "Skip=1 Tokens=*" %%G IN ('WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET Manufacturer') DO (SET "DeviceOEM=%%G")
ECHO OEM: %DeviceOEM%
PAUSE
```

However all I get is "ECHO OEM:", which indicates that %DeviceOEM% is blank.

Now if I run

```
FOR /F "Skip=1 Tokens=*" %%G IN ('WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET Manufacturer') DO (ECHO %%G)
PAUSE
```

Then I get a real answer of my OEM.

I don't understand where this SET command is failing.

Comment: For the reason of getting the environment variable not defined with the value as expected by you see my answer on [How to correct variable overwriting misbehavior when parsing output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965431/3074564) There are multiple solutions for this problem. Which one is best depends on which __WMIC__ command line is used to get which data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `delim` is issued on `=` it will only assign the value after the `=` to the value. We therefore change the `wmic` command to issue the result with `/value` which will return `Manufacturer=<name of OEM>` where we only use everything post `=`

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=2*delims==" %%G in ('WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET Manufacturer /value') do SET "DeviceOEM=%%G"
echo OEM: %DeviceOEM%
```

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer with an explanation. It's simpler and does not add quotation marks to the variable. I'll have to remember the "/value" parameter.

Comment: It is easy to remember that. Just bookmark this question. It is on the left of your question below the up/downvote area.