# Subsonic ORM Generator Output in CHINESE

Tags: visual-studio, orm, subsonic

Running VS 2017. I have been using the Subsonic ORM in my ASP.NET web application for a while now. All of a sudden when I run it (via a command I setup as an external tool in VS) the output is in Chinese! Any idea why?

The command I am running is:

```
generate /config "C:\Users\xxxx\project\web.config" /out "C:\Users\xxxx\project\SubSonic" /provider Default
```

The stackoverflow article here did not answer my question: [Cmd.exe output in Chinese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287761/cmd-exe-output-in-chinese). Also, this didn't either: [cmd is somehow writing chinese text as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210553/cmd-is-somehow-writing-chinese-text-as-output)

The output window results in alot of Chinese characters.

Any suggestions? I've restarted VS a few times and double-checked that my command line was the same as before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out! When setting up your external tool in VS make sure "Treat output as Unicode" is NOT CHECKED. I'm not sure why it was checked all of a sudden, but anyways it works now!