# FOR /F doesn't work when using it to read text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-line, cmd

I know this question has been asked in all shapes and forms on here, and my syntax seems to be correct, I can't understand where I am going wrong.

When using

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=." %%G IN ("7.1.2.12") DO ECHO This is G: %%G
```

in cmd.exe I get an output of 12, as expected.

If I put that number into a file version.txt for example

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=." %%G IN (version.txt) DO ECHO This is G: %%G
```

I don't get any output or error, nothing!

Even when explicit about the directory

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=." %%G IN (C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\version.txt) DO ECHO This is G: %%G
```

I looked into `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`but don't think it applies in my situation (I eventually want to `SET` `%%G` to a variable.)

**Sidenote:** I am using the double % because I'm running it from a batch file.

Any ideas?
Any more info needed?

Comment: Errrrrm... I tested that with literally copied code from your question... Works totally fine. Make sure they are exactly same name and in the same directory; add a pause at the end of the batch-file and comment out the probably existing `@echo off` to see every step happening when executed. Using that you hopefully can determine what happened. Even with a leading new line it works perfectly fine... Only idea is that you have probably not saved the file/not wrote the version correctly. This will leed to the echo not beeing executed...

Comment: check the coding of your textfile. Should be plain text (in notepad "save as" coding "ANSI").

Comment: I've definitely seen for loops get broken by a lack of ANSI before.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! My sanity is restored!. The only issue is the file is created from batch script, how can I get it to default to ANSI as opposed to Unicode?

Comment: There should be no usual reason why your batch file is outputting unicode. One additional thing to bear in mind is that if there are spaces in the path within the parentheses you'll need to place it in double quotes and use the usebackq option. `"usebackq tokens=4 delims=." %%G IN ("C:\Users\Myname\My Folder\version.txt")`

Comment: What command is creating version.txt?

Comment: In case of `wmic` output is redirected into `version.txt` and later processed, look on answers of [How to correct variable overwriting misbehavior when parsing output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961755/) and [cmd is somehow writing Chinese text as output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210553/).

Comment: To convert the Unicode text file to an ANSI text file during reading, you could use the following code: `for /F "tokens=4 delims=." %%G in ('type "version.txt"') do echo This is G: %%G`...

Comment: Thanks guys, in the end I went for  <br/>

`WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Company\\Application.exe" get Version>C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\UNIversion.txt`  <br/>

`REM Converting the extracted file from UNICODE to ASCII:`  <br/>
`CMD /A /C TYPE UNIversion.txt > ASCIIversion.txt`

Answer (score 0):

not sure whether this would be help. But I am having the same issue this afternoon and spent more than 1 hour until i saw this thread. Basically I created that "version.txt" inside MS Powershell by "dir > version.txt", and the For /F didnt work. Until i have delete the version.txt, then re-run the same command in CMD. Then For /F works.

Answer (score 0):

Do `chcp 65001` (utf-8 at the start of script).
and save the file as utf-8.