# How do I use a variable within some parameter using Batch?

Tags: batch-file

```
::Set the command to cmd
set cmd="wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get sid"

::Set the output to variable User
set "User="
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('%cmd%') do if not defined User set "User=%%i"

::Output the variable
echo %User%

::This part doesn't work
::Change registry key, using variable as placeholder
reg add "HKEY_USERS\%User%\example" /v exampleKey /d "1" /t REG_DWORD /f

pause >nul
```

I thought it would work, but apparently I'm doing something wrong. I get:

ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: Your methodology is wasted, HKU\YourSID is automatically mapped to HKCU, so there's no reason not to `REG ADD "HKCU\Example"`.

Comment: @Compo In my specific case there is a reason I'm doing it this way, but I didn't explain that part, because it's irrelevant.

Comment: Do you mean that you're not really using %UserName%? If you're after other users that can also be ascertained through WMIC too. _(But that would be a separate question)._

Comment: @Compo Well, for whatever reason, the program whose registry key I'm trying to change hides the registry hive from HKCU, but it can still be found by going to the specific SID location. I don't know why this is, but to navigate around the issue, I have to get the current user's SID number, then go to their specific hive. If I try to edit the registry from HKCU, it can't find the key location. Like I said, I don't know how the program manages to do that, but I've found a way to work around it.

Comment: Even if the key was somehow 'hidden'; because HKCU is effectively a link to the HKU location, your forced write of a key value and data shouldn't not take. That said, I still provided a direct solution to your question, which you appear to have ignored and would appreciate your feedback on it's effectiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why first assigning the command to execute by **FOR** to an environment variable enclosed in double quotes and then reference the value of that environment variable with immediate expansion.

It makes a huge difference where the first double quote is placed on assigning a string to an environment variable as it can be read for example on [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564)

It would be better to specify the **WMIC** command line directly and escape the equal sign with caret character `^` and use additionally the option `/VALUE` to get `SID=...` output on a line.

```
::Set the output to variable UserSID
set "UserSID="
for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (`%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe UserAccount where name^='%USERNAME%' GET SID /VALUE`) do set "UserSID=%%I"

::Output the variable
echo UserSID=%UserSID%

::Change registry key, using variable as placeholder.
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe add "HKEY_USERS\%UserSID%\example" /V exampleKey /D 1 /T REG_DWORD /F
```

### Explanation why code in question fails and this one works

The command **WMIC** outputs always in Unicode which means with 2 bytes per character using UTF-16 Little Endian encoding with Byte Order Mark (BOM).

For example the output of the command

```
wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get sid
```

redirected into a file is

```
000h: FF FE 53 00 49 00 44 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ; ÿþS.I.D. . . . .
010h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  . . . . . . . .
020h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  . . . . . . . .
030h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  . . . . . . . .
040h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  . . . . . . . .
050h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  . . . . . . . .
060h: 0D 00 0A 00 53 00 2D 00 31 00 2D 00 35 00 2D 00 ; ....S.-.1.-.5.-.
070h: 32 00 31 00 2D 00 31 00 39 00 35 00 37 00 39 00 ; 2.1.-.1.9.5.7.9.
080h: 39 00 34 00 34 00 38 00 38 00 2D 00 36 00 38 00 ; 9.4.4.8.8.-.6.8.
090h: 38 00 37 00 38 00 39 00 38 00 34 00 35 00 2D 00 ; 8.7.8.9.8.4.5.-.
0a0h: 31 00 38 00 30 00 31 00 36 00 37 00 34 00 35 00 ; 1.8.0.1.6.7.4.5.
0b0h: 33 00 31 00 2D 00 31 00 30 00 30 00 33 00 20 00 ; 3.1.-.1.0.0.3. .
0c0h: 20 00 0D 00 0A 00 0D 00 0A 00                   ;  .........
```

which is displayed in a command prompt window as:

```
SID············································•¶
S-1-5-21-1957994488-688789845-1801674531-1003··•¶
•¶
```

**Note:** The character `·` is used here and below as placeholder for a space character, `•` represents a carriage return and `¶` represents a line-feed to make the whitespace characters visible.

Command **FOR** processes captured output with one byte per character. So it should process:

```
000h: 53 49 44 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ; SID             
010h: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ;                 
020h: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 0D ;                .
030h: 0A 53 2D 31 2D 35 2D 32 31 2D 31 39 35 37 39 39 ; .S-1-5-21-195799
040h: 34 34 38 38 2D 36 38 38 37 38 39 38 34 35 2D 31 ; 4488-688789845-1
050h: 38 30 31 36 37 34 35 33 31 2D 31 30 30 33 20 20 ; 801674531-1003  
060h: 0D 0A 0D 0A                                     ; ....
```

That text would be output into command prompt window exactly like the Unicode text.

But **FOR** does not make a good job on converting Unicode to ASCII/ANSI/OEM. The result is that **FOR** processes:

```
000h: 53 49 44 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ; SID             
010h: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ;                 
020h: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 0D ;                .
030h: 0D 0A 53 2D 31 2D 35 2D 32 31 2D 31 39 35 37 39 ; ..S-1-5-21-19579
040h: 39 34 34 38 38 2D 36 38 38 37 38 39 38 34 35 2D ; 94488-688789845-
050h: 31 38 30 31 36 37 34 35 33 31 2D 31 30 30 33 20 ; 1801674531-1003  
060h: 20 0D 0D 0A                                     ;  ...
```

This text printed to command output window would be:

```
SID············································••¶
S-1-5-21-1957994488-688789845-1801674531-1003··••¶
```

So instead of having two data lines terminated with carriage return and line-feed and one empty line also terminated with carriage return and line-feed, the result is two data lines with being terminated with two carriage returns and a line-feed. This might not be what **FOR** really parses internally, but what can be seen on using just `"delims="` and as command `echo %%i` with output redirected into a file.

The wrong conversion of `0D 00 0A 00` to `0D 0D 0A` instead of `0D 0A` is a big problem because of causing weird parsing of the last two lines output by **WMIC**.

There are two interpretations possible and it depends on version of Windows what happens:

1. The last line with data is interpreted as data line with an additional carriage return at end not being discarded on assigning the complete line to the loop variable and next to the environment variable.
   This happens here on Windows XP.
   The environment variable `User` has assigned after the **FOR** loop with `"skip=1 delims="` the string: `S-1-5-21-1957994488-688789845-1801674531-1003··•`
2. The last line with data is interpreted as data line being first assigned to loop variable and next to environment variable.
   Then **FOR** processes one more line containing just a carriage return which is also assigned to loop variable and which would be also assigned to the environment variable.
   This happens here on Windows Vista and later versions of Windows.
   The **IF** condition `if not defined User` prevents overwriting value of environment variable `User` having already the SID assigned by just a carriage return.
   The environment variable `User` has assigned after the **FOR** loop with `"skip=1 delims="` the string: `S-1-5-21-1957994488-688789845-1801674531-1003··`

So it should be clear now why the `reg add` command line fails although the output of environment variable `User` not making the whitespace characters visible looks right. The environment variable contains either two spaces or two spaces and a carriage return at end after the SID string.

Now let us look on output of the command line

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe UserAccount where name='%USERNAME%' GET SID /VALUE
```

by redirecting the output into a file and looking on it with a hex viewer/editor

```
000h: FF FE 0D 00 0A 00 0D 00 0A 00 53 00 49 00 44 00 ; ÿþ........S.I.D.
010h: 3D 00 53 00 2D 00 31 00 2D 00 35 00 2D 00 32 00 ; =.S.-.1.-.5.-.2.
020h: 31 00 2D 00 31 00 39 00 35 00 37 00 39 00 39 00 ; 1.-.1.9.5.7.9.9.
030h: 34 00 34 00 38 00 38 00 2D 00 36 00 38 00 38 00 ; 4.4.8.8.-.6.8.8.
040h: 37 00 38 00 39 00 38 00 34 00 35 00 2D 00 31 00 ; 7.8.9.8.4.5.-.1.
050h: 38 00 30 00 31 00 36 00 37 00 34 00 35 00 33 00 ; 8.0.1.6.7.4.5.3.
060h: 31 00 2D 00 31 00 30 00 30 00 33 00 0D 00 0A 00 ; 1.-.1.0.0.3.....
070h: 0D 00 0A 00 0D 00 0A 00                         ; ........
```

and also printing into console window

```
•¶
•¶
SID=S-1-5-21-1957994488-688789845-1801674531-1003•¶
•¶
•¶
```

There are no spaces anymore. The name of the value and its current value are printed on one line with an equal sign between. Two really empty lines are output additionally by **WMIC** above and below on using option `/VALUE` with that value query.

Of course the command **FOR** does again the conversion from Unicode to ASCII/ANSI/OEM not correct which could be again a problem. But this time the **FOR** options are different in comparison to code in question.

`"usebackq tokens=2 delims=="` means that the equal sign is a delimiter character to split up the line into multiple strings (tokens) and only the second string (token) is of interest for further processing. Empty lines are always skipped by command **FOR**. But the command `set "UserSID=%%I"` is also not executed if **FOR** fails to determine a none empty *SECOND* string from the parsed line. For that reason only third line with `SID=...` is resulting in execution of **SET** command, and end of **WMIC** output being misinterpreted as line having only a carriage return is ignored like an empty line because no string after an equal sign can be found here by **FOR**.

The different **WMIC** output with different **FOR** parsing results in environment variable `UserSID` having assigned the value:

```
S-1-5-21-1957994488-688789845-1801674531-1003
```

There are no whitespaces at end of the environment variable value.

And now the `reg add` command line works of course as there are no trailing whitespaces anymore.

See also the answers on the questions [How to correct variable overwriting misbehavior when parsing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961755/) and [cmd is somehow writing chinese text as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210553/) on how to get Unicode output of **WMIC** correct converted to ASCII/ANSI/OEM if it is not possible to change output format of **WMIC** and use a different data parsing by command **FOR** to workaround the line ending conversion bug of **FOR**.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked for me, but I don't completely understand your explanation. How does your method work?

Answer (score 0):

If there was a good reason to write to that key instead of the mapped HKCU key then I'd do it like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC UserAccount Where (Name='%UserName%') Get SID"') Do For %%B In (%%A
) Do Reg Add "HKU\%%B\Example" /V ExampleKey /T Reg_DWord /D 1 /F>Nul
```