# How to get file version of a DLL or EXE to a variable using WMIC in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

I try to get the file version using a Windows batch file. This command successfully prints the version to console.

```
WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="Z:\\bin\\My_project.dll" get Version /format:Textvaluelist
```

But when I try to get this output to a variable using the below method, Windows command processor outputs:

> Z:\\bin\\My_project.dll - Invalid alias verb.

What is wrong on this command line?

```
for /f %%a in ('WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="Z:\\bin\\My_project.dll" get Version /format:Textvaluelist') do set val=%%a
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd attempt this task using `WMIC`:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In (
    'WMIC DataFile Where "Name='Z:\\bin\\My_project.dll'" Get Version /Value 2^>Nul'
) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%C In ("%%B") Do Set "val=%%C"
```

*The second `For` loop is designed to overcome the unwanted output resulting from the unicode `WMIC` result.*

---

**Edit**

If `WMIC` wasn't stipulated, you could utilise `VBScript` from your batch file:

Using Windows Scripting Host:

```bat
<!-- :
@Echo Off
For /F %%A In ('CScript //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"') Do Set "val=%%A"
Set val 2>Nul
Pause
Exit /B

-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
  WScript.Echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFileVersion("Z:\bin\My_project.dll")
</Script></Job>
```

Or via `mshta.exe`:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F %%A In ('
    MsHTA VBScript:Execute("Set o=CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject""):o.GetStandardStream(1).Write(o.GetFileVersion(""Z:\bin\My_project.dll"")):Close"^)
') Do Set "val=%%A"
Set val 2>Nul
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the equal-to sign in your `where` clause, which is seen as a standard token separator by `cmd`, just like <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;`, the vertical tab (code `0x0B`), the form-feed (code `0x0C`) and the non-break space (code `0xFF`).

The `for /F` command executes the command to be parsed in a separate `cmd` instance, but before doing that, every sequence of standard token separators becomes replaced by a single <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. So also the `=` becomes replaced, which leaves some odd syntax behind.

To literally keep the `=`-sign you need to escape it like `^=`. An alternative way is to change quotation style so that the `=` appears in between `""`, by stating `wmic DataFile where "Name='Z:\\bin\\My_project.dll'" get Version`.

But this still does not deliver the expected result, because `wmic` returns Unicode output, which leaves some disturbing conversion artefacts like orphaned carriage-return characters behind. This can be avoided by nesting another `for /F` loop.

Additionally, because of your output chosen format, you would also get a `Version=` prefix, which is probably not what you want to be included. This can be changed by defining suitable `tokens` and `delims` options for `for /F`.

All these items lead to a code like the following:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`
    wmic DataFile where "Name='Z:\\bin\\My_project.dll'" get Version /VALUE
`) do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do set "val=%%c"
```

This would remove any leading `=`-signs from the returned version, if there were any.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to get version of a DLL is using this command line in a batch file:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE WHERE name^="Z:\\bin\\My_project.dll" get Version /VALUE 2^>nul') do set "val=%%I"
```

Also possible is this slightly different command line in a batch file:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (`%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE WHERE "name='Z:\\bin\\My_project.dll'" GET Version /VALUE 2^>nul`) do set "val=%%I"
```

**FOR** runs the command in the round brackets using a separate command process started with `%ComSpec% /c` in the background and captures all lines output to **STDOUT** of this command process. For that reason it must be taken into account how `cmd.exe` instance currently processing the batch file parses the entire command line and how **FOR** processes the argument strings within the round brackets.

A redirection operator like `>` outside a double quoted string must be escaped with `^` to get it interpreted first as literal character when Windows command processor parses the command line before executing **FOR**.

And an equal sign `=` outside a double quoted string is interpreted by **FOR** as an argument separator like a space or a comma as it can be seen on running in a command prompt window for example:

```
for %I in ("space ' ' and comma ',' and equal sign '='" space,comma=equal_sign) do @echo %I
```

This command line outputs:

```
"space ' ' and comma ',' and equal sign '='"
space
comma
equal_sign
```

For that reason also `=` outside a double quoted string must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted first as literal character.

The second solution uses an alternate **WMIC** syntax to embed the equal sign in a double quoted string and a different **FOR** syntax using back quotes to be able to use `'` in command line to execute by **FOR**.

**WMIC** outputs with option `/VALUE` or `/FORMAT:Textvaluelist` for example:

```
 
 
Version=1.0.0.11
```

So the **WMIC** output consists of two empty lines, the queried information `Version` with an equal sign and the version value, and two more empty lines.

The problem is that **WMIC** outputs always the queried data using UTF-16 Little Endian character encoding with byte order mark (BOM) and **FOR** has a bug on processing this Unicode output correct. **FOR** interprets a byte sequence with the hexadecimal values `0D 00 0A 00` being UTF-16 LE encoded the line ending carriage return + line-feed as `0D 0D 0A`. So there is an erroneous carriage return at end of the real line ending removed by **FOR** before processing further the remaining string.

For details about this **FOR** bug see for example:

- [How to correct variable overwriting misbehavior when parsing output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961755/)
- [cmd is somehow writing Chinese text as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210553/)

This bug is worked around here **partly** by using option `/VALUE` to get the wanted information output by **WMIC** on one line in format `Version=value` and using **FOR** options `tokens=2 delims==`. Only the captured line with `Version=value` has two strings separated by an equal sign and so the command **SET** is executed only on this line with the value after the equal sign. The two empty lines before and the two empty lines after line with version information, wrong interpreted by **FOR** as lines with just a carriage return, do not result in executing command **SET** as there is no second string which could be assigned to loop variable `I`.

It is expected by this code that the version string does not contain itself one or more `=` which should be always the case for version of a DLL.

**Note 1:** The value of environment variable `val` is unmodified respectively this environment variable is still not defined if any error occurs like the DLL file is not found at all. The error message output by **WMIC** is suppressed by redirecting it with `2>nul` (with escaping `>`) from **STDERR** to device **NUL**.

**Note 2:** The version string assigned to the environment variable `val` has as last character the erroneous carriage return. That must be taken into account on further processing the string value of `val`. The solutions of [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496989/3074564) and [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497153/3074564) using two **FOR** loops as posted are better because the environment variable `val` is defined with the version string of the DLL without the erroneous carriage return.